# JPA2 cache or hibernate cache

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, caching, jpa-2.0

I like to create a new project the integration tier based on hibernate and JPA 2 , i need to use persistance cache .

What's the difference between jpa2 cache and hibernate cache ?

what's the advantage and disadvantages of each cache ?

Comment: JPA is a specification. Hibernate is an implementation of that specification. I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "persistance cache", but since Hibernate and JPA are, basically, the same thing, what you call jpa2 cache and hibernate cache are also the same thing.

Comment: as i know they are not the same architecure there are a big difference . i search for this

Comment: What is "they"? Could you provide a concrete example of what you mean by "JPA2 cache" and a concrete example of what you mean by "Hibernate cache"? What are the "big differences"?

Comment: Make sure you're not confusing "Hibernate Core" (as it was before 2009, with `Session` and all) and "Hibernate ORM/JPA" (as it was after 2009, with `EntityManager` and all). For some unclear reason starters still value outdated and poorly maintained amateuristic tutorial sites full of advertisements on the Internet over real Java EE books from the shelf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually JPA2 is specification and Hibernate is implementation of this specification.

None of them provides cache implementation, except session cache (your entities within single transaction/session interaction)

If you plan to add possibility to replace hibernate, then use pure JPA2 annotations and configurations.

Hibernate's annotation @Cache provides a bit more fine grained control on how entities are stored in cache, JPA's @Cacheable provides only possibility either to include in cache or not (all the control of storage in cache is defined in the general JPA configuration and caching implementation).